# Creating SEO friendly URLs using apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to convert my ugly URL into SEO friendly URLs using apache `mod_rewrite`.

This is how my current `URL`s look like:

```
index.php?p=search
index.php?p=contact
index.php?p=my-account&user=1
index.php?p=my-account&user=1
```

This is what I expect from rewriting:

```
mydomain.com/search
mydomain.com/contact
mydomain.com/my-account/1
mydomain.com/my-account/1
```

If I passed one query string through my URL. I can do it in my `.htaccess` file something like this. But not sure how to do it when query string more than one in `URL`.

```
# Create SEO friendly URL 
# Eg: index.php?p=search to domain/search
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Turn on the engine:
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect certain paths to index.php:
RewriteRule ^(search|contact)/?$ index.php?p=$1 

</ifModule>
```

This is working if URL has one string. 
Can anybody tell me how I do this for more query strings.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Turn on the engine:
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect certain paths to index.php:
RewriteRule ^(search|contact)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&user=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

</ifModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your aswer.. So how I change my `<a>` tag?

Comment: If I use one string my `<a>` look like this - `<a href="search>`

Comment: You can have `<a href="/my-account/1">Something</a>` and `<a href="/search">Search</a>`

Comment: Do I need to use `absolute` path for my CSS and JS?

Comment: Yes you should otherwise you can also add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Do I need to add this `<base href="/" />`  in  `<head>` ?

Comment: Yes add it to fix css/js path issues if not using absolute paths

Comment: `<head><base href="/" /></head>` I tried it... But not working. When I using for single query it worked without using absolute path.. Whats the reasion to happen this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80066/discussion-between-tnk-and-anubhava).